# Dependent module libdb2.a(shr.o) could not be loaded

Tags: php, apache, db2, aix

I have been trying to connect to DB2 from PHP script.

When I include the right `ibm_db2.so` files in `php.ini` and restart apache following this, it would not load the modules.

Also in apache error log I see some messages like:

```
PHP Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 
'/opt/freeware/lib/php/modules/ibm_db2_5.2.1.so' -/t0509-022 
Cannot load module '/opt/freeware/lib/php/modules/ibm_db2_5.2.1.so' \n\t0509-150
Dependent module libdb2.a(shr.o) could not be loaded. \n\t0509-022
```

Any help with this problem is too much appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Looks like you don't have the DB2 client correctly installed.

Comment: I think the problem lies with the configuration of DB2 in `httpd.conf`.
Is it necessary to include db2profile path in `httpd.conf`

Comment: Not sure what you mean by that: there are no DB2 configuration items in `httpd.conf`. But then again, if you think so...

Comment: How to go about this problem.
`Dependent module libdb2.a(shr.o) could not be loaded. \n\t0509-022`
Because I strongly feel that DB2 client is installed correctly.

Comment: If the DB2 client is properly set up, then the other possible reason is that the PHP environment does not point to the DB2 libraries, so the loader does not know where to look for them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you paste the output of:

dump -H /opt/freeware/lib/php/modules/ibm_db2_5.2.1.so

You will see a lines like:

```
INDEX  PATH                          BASE                MEMBER              
0      /usr/lib:/lib:/usr/lpp/xlC/lib                                         
1 ...
```

The 0th entry is used to look for a file called libdb2.a with a member of shr.o.  This is if LIBPATH is not set.  If LIBPATH is set, then the components in LIBPATH are used.  The loaded is not finding that file.

Or... it can find it but can not load it.  If you can find it and its in a place that the loader should see, then extract that piece:

```
ar x libdb2.a shr.o
```

then do:

```
dump -H shr.o
```

rinse and repeat... i.e. find that it depends upon and see if those dependencies exist.  There is also the chance that shr.o is not the same bitsize.  i.e. you have a 64 bit application and shr.o is a 32 bit object file.  That would surprise me but its possible (if I recall correctly).  To check the bit size do:

```
file shr.o
```

and it will have "64 bit" in the description if it is a 64 bit binary and it will not have it if it is a 32 bit binary.

Good luck